# Trying to add shapes to a Group without drawing them to the screen(CMU CS academy)

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a class for objects in my game, and I want them to have a parts parameter, that I can call draw() on, when I want it drawn. However, whenever I want to Group{} CMU's built in objects, it draws them automatically. I want to be able to use CMU's collision checking and easier movement with centerX and centerY without drawing automatically. Essentially trying to create a Group object without drawing it.

What I want:

```
def move(self, x, y):
     self.posX += x
     self.posY += y
     self.parts.centerX += x
     self.parts.centerY += y
parts = Group {
Circle(200, 200, 5, fill="red"),
Rect(200, 200, 50, 50, fill="blue")
}
player = Player(100, 100, "filler", parts)

player.move(2, 2)

player.draw() # now draws the parts
```

What I get:

```
def move(self, x, y):
     self.posX += x
     self.posY += y
     self.parts.centerX += x
     self.parts.centerY += y
parts = Group {
Circle(200, 200, 5, fill="red"),
Rect(200, 200, 50, 50, fill="blue")
}# draws the parts
player = Player(100, 100, "filler", parts)

player.move(2, 2) # draws the parts 

player.draw()
```